# Advice with a "Story Roblox Creator Challenge" project I'm working on

Tags: lua, storyboard, roblox

So I was bored and decided to work on a Roblox game. I'm currently using the "Story Roblox Creator Challenge" template but I don't know how to make it do what I want it to do...

Here is the code so far. For some reason, it doesn't show both questions and says "PlayerName" instead of my username

,,

```
local name01 = storyMaker:GetInput("What Is Your Name?") 
local gender01 = storyMaker;GetInput ("Are You A Boy Or A Girl?") 

local story = "My name is " .. name01 .. ", /n "I Was Just Your Average" .. gender01 ". "
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes... Why Do You Ask?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Sorry About That... I Didn't Know How To Word It And Also Didn't Think To Check The Tutorial Page For The Challenge...

Comment: Why does it say it is closed? I'm quite confused.

Comment: I've created an edit that if approved will clean up this question a bit and remove the "(closed)" text from the title. @9puppys, if you found a solution to your problem, it would be great if you could type it out as an answer to your question with the "Answer Your Question" button

Answer (score 1):

In the variable gender01, there is a semicolon between storyMaker and GetInput.
Also "I Was Just Your Average" is not inside a string,
and you are putting a variable inside a string, which will return "gender01" instead of the variable's value, and there is a period not inside a string.
The Code Should Be:

```
local name01 = storyMaker:GetInput("What Is Your Name?") 
local gender01 = storyMaker:GetInput("Are You A Boy Or A Girl?") 

local story = "My name is " .. name01 .. ", /n I Was Just Your Average".. gender01.."."
```

I am not a expert at roblox lua but it might help anyways.